# Как прописать заголовки CORS для axios на Vue?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, cors

Есть ajax запрос к json файлу. В консоле приходит ошибка CORS.Проект на Vue.
App.vue

```
...
 created() {

this.axios.get("http://localhost/data.json", {
    headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }
   })
    .then(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
       }
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from "./js/router"
import VueAxios from "vue-axios"
import axios from "axios"


Vue.use(VueAxios, axios) 

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Подскажите как можно избежать ошибку.

Comment: Это неверные настройки сервера ( Не JS). Добавьте свой домен на сервере.

Comment: Вообще то CORS прописывается на стороне Back End. С клиентской стороны ты ничего не можешь сделать

Answer (score 0):

Только настроить сервер, на клиенте проблема не решается